# Maxent species distribution

Tags: raster, esri-ascii-raster, maxent

I am in the process of developing distribution map in MAXENT. My species habitat is subset of another mammal habitat. I have distribution layer digitised for mammal species, rasterised and converted to asc. Apparently the raster dimensions are slightly different. If I edit the asc file in word the features disappeared. Need help on how to go about it.

Comment: You probably shouldn't edit ASC files in word.  Notepad might work, but you would be better of using a text editor that supports all types of encoding.  Notepad++ for instance.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment above, ASC files have certain control characters that are corrupted if you open and save the file in an application like word.

Try using notepad or notepad++ instead.